# Datepicker format in vb.net to ms access Feb 11, 2022 read as Nov/02/2022

Tags: vb.net, datepicker

Datepicker format in vb.net to MS access Feb 11, 2022 read as Nov/02/2022

Here is my code

```
strSQL = "SELECT * " &
 "FROM Payroll " &
 "WHERE EmpID = '" & strSelectedAssignCode & "' And FromPay = #" & dtpFromPay.Value.Date & "# And ToPay = #" & dtpToPay.Value.Date & "#"


cnOleDb = New OleDbConnection(ACCESS_CONNECTION_STRING)
cnOleDb.Open()

cmSQL = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, cnOleDb)
drSQL = cmSQL.ExecuteReader()
```

[image]

Comment: I would start by changing your code to do the database update using parameters and not string concatenation. Once that is done, see if the dates are working correctly.

Comment: As @AndrewMortimer said, always use parametrized querys, always, then use a .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") that seems is the date format used by your DataBase when adding the value of dates to the parameters array